# Password reset: First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I'm trying send a password reset link to users' email and receiving the error as in the title of this question.

Here's my resetpassword.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { User } from "../../models/user";

/**
 * Generated class for the ResetpasswordPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-resetpassword',
  templateUrl: 'resetpassword.html',
  providers: [AngularFireAuth]
})
export class ResetpasswordPage {
  resetMsg: string="Reset"
  user = {} as User

  constructor(private afauth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: 
NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  async reset(user: User) {
    try{
      const result = 
this.afauth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.user.email);
      if(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

}
}
```

Here's the code in user.ts file in models folder:

```
export interface User {

    email: string;
    password: string;

}
```

This code below is the part of the html file:

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
      <button class="reset" (click)="reset(user)" ion-button round medium icon-end color="primary">
        {{ resetMsg }}
        <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
      </button>
```

Creating the user, login is all good but unable to send the reset password email. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.user.email)` output?

Comment: code: "auth/argument-error", message: "sendPasswordResetEmail failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string." is what it throws as output. Not sure why the email is not being considered as valid string

Comment: if you getting the correct email in console log try something like this `this.user.email.toString`  or wrap it as String.

Comment: I'm not asking what error you are getting, I'm want to know if you are indeed sending a string. :-) To do this I'd like to know what `console.log(this.user.email)` outputs in the console. Put that line at the top of the `try`.

Comment: @camden_kid when I put the code you provided before "try", output in the console is testaccount@gmail.com which is the email I'm using and is a registered account in this Ionic app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the underlying issue. But it took me to compile the code again and running the ionic serve command in a new instance to get the issue fixed. @camden_kid your answer helped me to confirm if the email is actually taken as string or not. Thanks!!!